# C++ switch statement , how does this work

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
if ( argc != 2 ) {
 std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <n> " << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
std::stringstream strm;
strm << argv[1];
int count = 0;
int number;
strm >> number;
switch ( number ) {
 case 0: ++count; 
 case 1: ++count; 
 case 2: ++count; 
 case 3: ++count; 
 case 4: ++count; 
 }

    std::cout << "count: " << count << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

I know this is a novice question, but i just started with C++. I took a game design course and this is the first example prof has on the SVN.  When I run the prog after compiling,

./run 4
(i.e. I give argument 4) I get an output: count: 1

./run 3
I get an output: count: 2

./run 1
count: 4

./run 0
count: 5

Since count is initialized to 0, how come ./run 1 gives 4 or ./run 0 give count 5.

I am really sorry for such a silly question, but I would appreciate any explanation.

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Answer (score 10):

With a `switch` statement, when control is passed to a `case` label, the code will continue on through all other `case` labels until a `break` or `return` (or other flow control mechanism) is encountered.  This can be useful for unifying logic of specific cases, and can also be used for more complicated tasks.  See for example: [a Duff's Device.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

Comment: Thanks, aww! "break" yes! I just read a thread here on C++ books. Hopefully I will come with better questions soon. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is the classic fall-through issue with switch statements. There are syntax checkers that will detect this because it is often (but not always) a bug. Fall-through can be quite handy, though, when you have values that require actions that differ only slightly.

Comment: @user1772218 -- don't feel too bad about this confusing you.  The "fall through by default on a `switch`/`case`" is a strange quirk of the C++ language.  (I, personally, would rather have had a `continue` to go on to the next `case` rather than a `break` to exit the `switch`)

Answer (score 3):

A switch statement defines where to enter a set of code.

```
switch ( number ) {
 case 0: ++count; //entrance point with number= 0
 case 1: ++count; //entrance point with number= 1
 case 2: ++count; //entrance point with number= 2
 case 3: ++count; //entrance point with number= 3
 case 4: ++count; //entrance point with number= 4
}
```

Inherently there is no exit except for getting to the end of the switch. However, it is possible to add a "break;" statement anywhere under a case to cause the code to exit the switch early (or break out of scope).

Additionally, but slightly off topic, the keyword "default" should be used in a case statement. The default keyword is called when the number doesn't have a defined case.  Example, using the case above, is if someone sent the number 6 to the case.

Comment: Good point about default. 
We use g++ 4.5.2 and with -Wall it will warn when you have an enumerated type as your switch varaible and not all defined values are covered in the case statements. Default will quiet this warning.